# Weird symbols coming out of matrices

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to print out individual values from the matrices from all images. However, the output that i am receiving are weird symbols and alphabets.
I have 60 images and each of them have a matrix of 320x240.
Sorry, my code may not be good or up to standard as i'm not very good in this.
Thanks :)

```
vector<Mat> images;
    for (int i = 0;i < 60;i++) {
        if (i < 10) {
            Mat in = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-0" + to_string(i) + "-mod.jpg", CV_8UC1);
            images.push_back(in);
        }
        else {
            Mat in = imread("ts_04-11-21_16-27-" + to_string(i) + "-mod.jpg", CV_8UC1);
            images.push_back(in);

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 320; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 240; k++) {
                cout << images[i].at<uint8_t>(j, k) << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to print the numbers as `uint8_t`, which is interpreted as characters by default. Try `cout << int(images[i].at<uint8_t>(j, k)) << endl;`.

Comment: This is an encoding problem, Jpegs are binary files, what are you expecting to get out of it?